# Is there a way to download dependencies jar from a Network location in Gradle 4.0?

Tags: java, gradle

Is there a way to download dependencies jar from a Network location in Gradle 4.0?

For example:

```
group 'com.hello'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'
    compile 'https://<hostname>:port/hello.jar' // can I do this?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle has had this capability before 4.0, but it requires you to establish your own Maven or Ivy repository.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:maven_repo

While I'm sure you could alternatively write some standard Groovy code to simply download a jar into the libs folder